# Selenium web-driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to use selenium web-driver on a production server in order to get content generated with javascript, and parse it with nokogiri(because I already have something done with it).

On my local machine, when I try opening a page with selenium it will open the browser as well, it will behave the same on a VPS?

If it will behave the same on a VPS, do I need to close the browser?, because I have to run throw millions of pages every day.

My VPS: is using Capistrano, with ruby on rails.

Are there any better solutions to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use Selenium with PhantomJS, which is an headless browser

Comment: Do i get the same results, as in a Browser simulation?

Comment: You should have the same results, but I've never actually used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [poltergeist gem](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) with capybara for similar task on server side. It uses headless webkit browser [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: How do you get the page source using this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Watir Web Driver + Headless gem which will not open any window.They both use Selenium.

[Headless gem](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless)

[Watir webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/)